# Facebook login button doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, firefox, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook's javascript SDK CDN and a button to log my users who prefers to login with their Facebook account.

However my Facebook login button works on every browser besides Firefox.

This is the button I'm implementing;

```
<button class="fb-login-button" data-scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();" name="facebook" value="facebook">FACEBOOK</button>
```

What's wrong with the code that deals with Firefox? It only refreshes the page on click.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Having same issue here, but no errors in console at all.  Using js sdk 2.5 for Facebook Audience Network.

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to fix the login button with:**

**The Refresh feature** (called "Reset" in older Firefox versions) can fix many issues by restoring Firefox to its factory default state while saving your bookmarks, history, passwords, cookies, and other essential information.

*Note: When you use this feature, you will lose any extensions, toolbar customization, and some preferences. See the Refresh Firefox - reset add-ons and settings article for more information.*

To Refresh Firefox:

- Open the Troubleshooting Information page using one of these
  methods: Click the menu button "top left corner", click help  and
  select Troubleshooting Information.

  *A new tab containing your troubleshooting information should open.*
  *If you're unable to access the Help menu, type about:support in your address bar to bring up the Troubleshooting Information page.*
- At the top right corner of the page, you should see a button that
  says "Refresh Firefox" ("Reset Firefox" in older Firefox versions).
  Click on it. Firefox will close. After the refresh process is
  completed, Firefox will show a window with the information that is
  imported.
- Click Finish and Firefox will reopen.